# Form submit not working via curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to a site using curl but for some reason when I use the print_r($login)  to view the output, I always end up seeing the original login page without it being processed (it was supposed to return something like login success or fail), I think curl is not able to submit the form, any suggestion?

```
$user="something"; $pass="something";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username={$user}&password={$pass}");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Something");  
$login = curl_exec($ch);  
print_r($login);
```

Comment: How POST request will be entertain if you don't enable it in CURL

Comment: @SunilPachlangia did you mean curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
```

To send POST content. Without it, your CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will be ignored.

Comment: Whar does not work ? The sending of the POST data, or their management on the distant site ?

Can you make a call to https://httpbin.org/post and paste the page's content, please ?

Comment: I only see the login form, if the POST data was being submitted I was supposed to see a login success or login failed return, there was supposed to be no field or forms, but everytime it prints only the original login form.

Comment: The remote site is alright, because if you go to the url from browser and enter the username and password and submit the form, it works fine by returning the login success/fail.

Comment: { "args": {}, "data": "", "files": {}, "form": { "password": "123", "username": "123" }, "headers": { "Accept": "*/*", "Content-Length": "25", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Host": "httpbin.org", "User-Agent": "Mozila/21.0.1985.125" }, "json": null, "origin": "xx.xx.xx.xx", "url": "http://httpbin.org/post" }

Comment: So, the post seems to work as intended. Is there a documentation on the distant site for sending login requests from your site? They also may prevent this. Can you tell which site it is?

Comment: Its a localhost, you cant access it.

Comment: What might be the kind of restrictions you are talking about?

Comment: The problem seems to be in this other local site, then. Can you make it dump the post data?

Comment: thats the problem, it seems nothing is being POSTed at all

Comment: It looks like curl is only loading the page, not submitting the form or anything at all.

Comment: How do you call $url on this local site?

Comment: there is a http at the beginning, stackoverflow is converting it to a url.

Comment: If you dump the post data at the beginning of the page and die immediately, what's the content of $login?

Comment: its the same as that with post data and just calling the url without any other parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126209/discussion-between-marc-brillault-and-adib).